# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.ibm.MFPApplication

Tags: class, exception, casting

We have an Cordova app which the following code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!((com.ibm.MFPApplication)this.getApplication()).hasCordovaSplashscreen()) {
        WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);
    }


    init();

    WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);
}
```

On the Android device and emulator, we got the following exception:

```
                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.ibm.MFPApplication
                                                 at io.cordova.hellocordova.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
```

.....

Any idea what might have caused this error and how to resolve this?

Thank you
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

be sure you have in AndroidManifest.xml file, in  node, the attribute **android:name="com.ibm.MFPApplication"**